# Landauer limit - cost to avoid changing a bit already equal to desired value

Tags: information, landauers-principle

If I have a bit and I do not know what the current value is, is it possible to use less energy than $E_b = k_b T \ln(2)$ so that if the bit value is already equal to what you want, you don't waste energy by setting it?

My guess is no: "observation/sampling" + "making a decision" would still involve a logic operation which would require the flipping of at least 1 bit.

Comment: > *"to not unnecessarily "erase" it"* What do you mean? Do you mean "to erase it"?

Comment: @JánLalinský changed it to “set”

Comment: > *"to not unnecessarily set it"* is still a confusing expression.

Comment: @JánLalinský is it better now? You know what I'm trying to say right?

Comment: Much better now.

Answer (score 0):

In real life, erasing an already erased bit need not dissipate energy. Consider dynamic RAM, where a "1" is a charged capacitor, but a "0" is discharged. Erase by draining charge from the capacitor through a resistor. If it's "1", you dissipate its energy, but if it's "0" you (on average) dissipate no energy (there is some transfer of energy from the capacitor to the resistor ("kTC noise"), but its direction is random).

I believe the Landauer limit is statistical, assuming maximum entropy of the medium before erasure.

Comment: “Erasure” in this context means to set a bit to whatever value you want. You didn’t answer my question: is sampling + making a decision always >= simply setting it?

Comment: @Bob In my example, you can have a circuit that sets the capacitor to anything you want by connecting it to a fixed voltage source. If the capacitor is already in the desired state, you dissipate no energy, but if it isn't, you dissipate energy. It doesn't even have to be binary.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer that doesn't depend on a physical setup i.e. just whether "sampling + decision" uses less energy than the cost to "erase"/set a bit.

Comment: @Bob The energy cost depends on the physical setup: it may be larger than the Landauer limit. But it can't (theoretically) be smaller, so a specific physical setup can tell you the answer to your question.

Comment: I’m asking about the theoretical best case value assuming that my setup can flip a bit at that limit. You’re focusing on an experimental value.

Comment: Theory emerges from experimental results. But my argument is pretty idealized and theoretical.